# How to get the value outside the onSuccess method in Android Java?

Tags: java, android, mobile-application

I need to get the userRole outside the onSuccess method in Android Java. How to get that?
I tried implementing interface and callback function and that also not worked.

```html
documentReference = firebaseFirestore.collection(
                "Users").document(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        documentReference.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        userRole = documentSnapshot.getString("userRole");

    }
});
```

Comment: Create a new global variable outside the code. Then assign the value to it inside the 
 onSuccess. Then you can get the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options you can use. The first one is using Mutablelivedata and the second is using an Interface. Assuming you are using MVVM pattern.

```
public Mutablelivedata<String> getuserRole(){
  documentReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
  documentReference.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      userRole.setValue(documentSnapshot.getString("userRole"));
    }
 });
return userRole;
}
```

then in your activity/fragment

```
yourViewModel.getuserRole.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new new Observer<String>(){
@Overrride
public void onChanged(String s){
//Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: your user role: "+s);
  }
});
```

The second is making an interface callback

```
public interface UserRoleInterface(){
  void userRole(String role);
}
```

Then set the interface as a parameter on your method/function

```
public void userRole(UserRoleInterface userRoleInterface){
 documentReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
 documentReference.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
  userRoleInterface.userRole(documentSnapshot.getString("userRole"));
 }
});
```

Then in your Activity/Fragment

```
yourViewModel.userRole(new UserRoleInterface(){
@Override
public void userRole(String role){
//Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: your user role: "+role);
}
});
```